# How can I debug a (.m) file in visual studio code (MacOS)by configure the file launch.json?

Tags: c, configuration, visual-studio-code

My computer's operation is MacOS Mojave(clang has been installed).The extension C/C++ has been installes too.How to configure launch.jason or what do I need to do else to compile the file successfully?

Comment: Is the `m` extension used for Objective-C?  Should change tag?

Comment: I want to use clang to debug C . m is a Script File ,I think.